# Renderizar legendas no vídeo com ffmpeg?

Tags: vídeo, legenda-de-gráfico

Tenho alguns arquivos de legenda que estão separados de seus respectivos vídeos, e eu gostaria de junta-los, usando o código abaixo:

```
ffmpeg -i videoSemLegenda.mp4 -i legenda.vtt -c copy -c:s mov_text videoComLegenda.mp4
```

Ao obter a saída no videoComLegenda usando `ffmpeg -i videoComLegenda.mp4`
A saída do ffmpeg mostra que a legenda está junto com o vídeo, porém ao tentar reproduzir o vídeo na tag `<video>` a legenda não é mostrada. Como faço para forçar a legenda a ser escrita dentro do vídeo?

Essa é a saída ffmpeg para um arquivo cuja as legendas foram colocar através do código acima:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x960 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1459 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 16k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(por): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(und): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874) (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
```

Comment: da uma lida nas respostas dessa pergunta no SO: [Use ffmpeg to add text subtitles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672809/use-ffmpeg-to-add-text-subtitles)

Comment: Os comandos lá passados funcionam da mesma maneira, colocam o arquivo de legenda dentro do recipiente mas os mesmos não aparecem no player

Comment: Eu não posso votar pra fechar na sua pergunta porque ela está com uma recompensa ativa. Mas eu acho que ela não faz parte do escopo do site porque não é sobre programação (e sim sobre o uso de um software).

Comment: Fiquei com uma dúvida, você quer "embeddar" a legenda para que ela seja renderizada junto ao vídeo, adicionar como track dentro do container ou simplesmente reproduzir um video com legenda usando o player nativo do elemento <video> ?

Comment: Mas @LuizVieira apesar da pergunta fazer referência a um software, a dúvida se aplica renderização de uma legenda dentro do vídeo para ser exibida dentro de uma tag <video>, logo não acredito que ela fuja do escopo do site, e no SO existem várias perguntas referentes ao mesmo software, logo não acredito que haja algum problema.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo quero que a legenda seja renderizada junto vídeo quando o mesmo for reproduzido em um player HTML

Comment: @LeoLetto Sim, ela se aplica à renderização da legenda dentro do vídeo. Ou, em outras palavras, a um uso do ffmpeg que não tem relação alguma com programação. Talvez existam perguntas referentes ao uso do mesmo software *em um contexto de programação* (como automatizar, como integrar, etc). Se não, eu também votaria para fechá-las.

Comment: Por ser um software Command-line acho que isso o inclui um pouco na categoria de programação.

Comment: @LeoLetto Se por acaso a sua intenção é fazer isso de forma automatizada dentro de um site (em PHP, talvez?) para o vídeo ser apresentado corretamente para o cliente HTML, deixe isso claro na questão. Aí sim eu acho que ela faria parte do escopo do site. :)

Comment: Discordo. Caso contrário, qualquer software se incluiria na categoria programação.

Comment: @LeoLetto Cara, você já tentou incluir a legenda como arquivo externo mesmo utilizando o <track>, como na referência do elemento?
http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_track_kind.asp

Comment: Sim sim @LeandroAngelo chamando a mesma através de um arquivo externo funciona perfeitamente, mas por motivos de curiosidade eu queria saber se é possível apenas embuti-la no vídeo

Comment: @LeoLetto Então só re-encodando o vídeo e de fato renderizar o texto junto a imagem. Tive que fazer isso há uns 3 anos e com mídias protegidas por DRM, fui o único jeito.

Comment: Olha só, Leo, como dá pra facilmente tornar a sua pergunta dentro do escopo, com base no que o colega @LeandroAngelo menciona. Acho que é só uma questão de vc editar a pergunta e melhorá-la incluindo essas informações do que você já tentou (e pode até mesmo mencionar que a sua busca por embutir trata-se de curiosidade - apesar de que a questão da proteção por DRM é bem relevante). Se editar nesse sentido, aliás, ganha o meu +1. :)

Comment: Eu não tenho intuito de fazer isso para proteger os arquivos, não vejo necessidade de editar a pergunta mudando o sentido da mesma, ta simples e objetiva de forma que também espero uma resposta simples, e não vejo por que o fator de ser uma pergunta só por "curiosidade" deveria influenciar na resposta. Enfim não vou discutir sobre até por que é proibido transformar comentários em chat. Peço desculpas a quem não gostou do escopo abordado na pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como você mesmo pôde ver nas informações do vídeo a legenda está codificada na segunda trilha de dados, inclusive, esta pode ser reproduzida normalmente pelos players que a suportem, mesmo que, talvez, seja necessário habilitar manualmente.

Você tem como alternativas utilizar a marcação `<track>` da tag  `<video>` desde que atente para as particularidades, limitações e possíveis problemas de cada navegador. Exemplo:

- Algumas versões do Internet Explorer não vai reconhecer legendas no formato VTT definidas por essa marcação a não ser que você defina o *Content-type* pelo servidor (*.htaccess* e similares)
- Chrome e Opera ignoram o atributo **default** e tentam combinar o idioma do browser com a legenda, provavelmente levando em conta o valor de `srclang`. 
  Comigo isso não funcionou. O ícone 'CC' sequer apareceu

Então, pelo sim pelo não, se o seu público alvo vai rumo à um único idioma, convém você embutir as legendas no vídeo:

```
ffmpeg -i "path/to/video.mp4" -vf srt="subtitle.srt" "path/to/video-subtitled.mp4"
```

Ou, se quiser estilizar a legenda, com o formato ASS (Advanced SubStation Alpha):

```
ffmpeg -i "path/to/video.mp4" -vf ass="subtitle.ass" "path/to/video-subtitled.mp4"
```

Caso precise converter de um formato pra outro, a FFMPEG também faz isso pra você:

```
ffmpeg -i "path/to/subtitle.srt" "path/to/subtitle.ass"
```

Agora se seu público alvo exigir múltiplas legendas, em múltiplos idiomas (e o Youtube não for uma opção ^_^), você vai mesmo ter que usar alguma biblioteca em JavaScript que dê conta do maior número de particularidades possível, nem que elas tenham que criar toda a UI do vídeo manualmente, como no [artigo do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video)

Answer (score 3):

O `HTML5` puro não dá suporte para legendas embutidas nos arquivos. O que você pode fazer é separar os arquivos e chamá-los como está abaixo:

```
<video controls preload="metadata">
   <source src="path/to/videos/my_video_1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <track label="Português" kind="subtitles" srclang="pt" src="path/to/captions/my_video_1.vtt" default>
</video>
```

Porém, existe um plugin, [mp4Box](https://github.com/gpac/mp4box.js), que consegue pegar essas legendas embutidas. Neste [link](https://github.com/gpac/mp4box.js#extraction), ele fala como extrair essas legendas.